# Relating MySQL-table content correctly

Tags: php, mysql, relational-database

I have the following tables in a database:

- products
- assembly_steps
- parts
- warnings

I want to relate the content of these tables as follows:
A product consists of many assembly_steps. An assembly_step can have different part and warnings. So I build the tables

- assembly_steps_has_parts
- assembly_steps_has_warnings
- products_has_assembly_steps

to relate the data. The ...*has*...-tables are connected with their related partners by foreign keys. I modeled that with the MySQL-Workbench.

I am confused about the mechanism to relate the info. How do I program that in PHP?

I think first you add the content on the lowest level, that would be parts and warnings. Then you add the assembly step and relate the data. But I don't know how to do this.

Here you find an overview: [Database-Model](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ewydw07xqay1jgo/db.png?dl=0)

Comment: can you give us an indication of the table structures?

Comment: I hope the link helps. If not, just tell me what else you might need to help :-). Let us just focus on the products/assembly_steps/parts/warnings.

Comment: `How do I program that` program WHAT?

Comment: How do I tell MySQL with PHP that part X with the ID a is related to assembly_step Y with the ID b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relational databases relate entities/values by recording them together in a row in a table.

To relate assembly_steps to parts, just insert a row into assembly_steps_has_parts, e.g. if you have the assembly_step_id in $assembly_step_id, and the part_id in $part_id, then:

```
INSERT INTO assembly_steps_has_parts (assembly_steps_id, parts_id)
VALUES ($assembly_step_id, $part_id)
```

Comment: Your answer proposes the right solution, however the mysql_insert_id()-function didn't come to my mind. So I still needed the comment @nomistic wrote.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't program this in PHP, you'd handle it fully with mysql.  The way this would be structured in mysql would be something like this:

```
assembly_steps   
assembly_id
assembly_description (or something like that
```

assembly_id is the primary key

```
parts
part_id
part_name
```

part_id is the primary key

```
assembly_steps_has_parts    
assemply_id
part_id
```

In this table, you'd have a **dual primary key**. Both assembly and part id are foreign keys **AND** primary keys for their respective tables.

The way that dual primary keys work is that there are ***two*** keys to make up one primary key on one table.  That means that instead of limiting to 1 key, it limits the table to one of any *combination* of these keys to make one.

For instance:

```
pk1  pk2
1     1
1     2
1     3
2     1
2     2
2     3
```

You could query them like this (this is a generic query, but the basic idea)

```
select a.assembly_description, p. part_name
from assembly_id a
join assembly_steps_has_parts ats
on a.assembly_id = ats.assembly_id 
join parts p
on ats.part_id = p.part_id
```

You'd do the same thing for the other tables.  From that point you'd just call the results of your query in php the way you would handle any other query.

Comment: I am not sure if I just don't have a clue, but my problem is not retrieving the related data (luckily I know how to use JOIN when I select data). I want to fill these ..._has_...-tables with the IDs used as foreign keys.

Comment: you aren't far off.   Just use dual primary keys in these "has" tables.  so for instance, you have table 1 (primary key: table1id), and table2 (primary key table2id).  table 3, the "has" table would just have **two** primary keys, which are also foreign keys, both table1id AND table2id.  that way they are linked to both other tables and it will allow any combination of relations between the two exactly once.

Comment: I think I already have that. table1id and table2id are both primary keys for their tables and foreign keys for the ..._has_...-table. My problem is that I don't know how to fill the rows in the ..._has_...-table with the foreign keys.

Comment: I think I begin to understand. I have to join the two primary keys in the ..._has_...-table?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  If you mean how to link them in php,   Look up insert_id. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php This basically will grab the last id you just entered, and insert it into another table.  this way if you are creating a new id, relation, it will ensure you insert the same id into multiple tables with the same id.

Comment: @nomistic A composite primary key is a single primary key, not two primary keys.

Comment: @reaanb yes, technicallly.  it means using two columns as a single primary key, but for all intents and purposes for the point of explanation, it's easier to understand this way, as when assigning them it's like assigning two keys